# Android Firebase database reference get detaild from where path is variable

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

In firebase functions we can

```
exports.vendor_Application = functions.database.ref(`vendor/back_office/application/{vendorUID}/`)
    .onWrite(async (change, context) => {
.....
});
```

We can get get details of different `vendorUID` when they get changed. That is change under that specific `vendorUID` which is a variable.

How do I implement this in Android?

```
databaseReference = `firebaseDatabase.getReference("vendor/back_office/application/ ????????? );`
```

and also get `vendorUID` value under which data was changed.

Comment: Did hscript's answer solve the problem?

Comment: this is one way, works, ok. but my database is large getting such a big snapshot everytime and sorting it for one section and discarding rest, will increase my bill in the long run

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Please also indicate the exact data you want to get.

Comment: @roysougat, did you check the suggestions from Alex in the above comment, were you able to get it.